# how to show sum(cost) and revenue from two tables and display per month

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, report

i have two tables:

```
table 1:
Expense cost
```

Posting Date

```
table 2:
Employee cost
Rvenue
```

Billing Date

```
Totalcost = Expense cost + Employee cost
Pofit Revenue - TotalCost
```

i have to display the report like so. It should show data per month according to year lets say 2011, (i know how to filter by year)

```
          Totalcost | Revenue | Profit
jan
feb
mar
apr
may 
jun
jul
aug
sep
oct
nov
dec
```

I'm having a tough time fugring out the query.
The problem is how can i display the data in report viewer table

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to combine the data to form a single data-table that will act as a data-source for the report.

You can join both tables at database side - for example,

```
SELECT
   t1.Month,
   t1.ExpenseCost + t2.EmployeeCost AS TotalCost,
   t2.Revenue,
   t2.Revenue - t1.ExpenseCost - t2.EmployeeCost AS Profit
FROM
   Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Year = t2.Year and t1.Month = t2.Month
WHERE
   t1.Year = @Year /* parameter to filter for a year */
```

or you can combine the data at front end either by using data relation or more simply by using LINQ over data tables - for example

```
var query = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                  join t1 in table2.AsEnumerable()
                  on t1.Field<string>("Month") equals t2.Field<string>("Month")
                  select new
                  {
                       Month = t1.Field<string>("Month"),
                       TotalCost = t1.Field<Decimal>("ExpenseCost") + t2.Field<Decimal>("EmployeeCost"),
                       Revenue = t2.Field<Decimal>("Revenue"), 
                       // similarly compute profit 
                   };
```

Comment: ok i get the query but how can i show it on the reportviewer cause i have 12 months to fill data for cost revenue and profit

Comment: @nikolomanabal, the query output is already in the desired format, all you have to do is to create a RDLC (or RDL) file with table data region - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251659%28v=VS.90%29.aspx